# mysql installation - failed with dependency error

Tags: mysql, linux, rpm

In my 32 bit linux system, i tried to install mysql 5.

```
#rpm -ivh MySQL-server-community-5.1.72-1.rhel5.i386.rpm MySQL-client-community-5.1.72-1.rhel5.i386.rpm

warning: MySQL-server-community-5.1.72-1.rhel5.i386.rpm: V3 DSA signature: NOKEY, key ID 5072e1f5
error: Failed dependencies:
        libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.3.4) is needed by MySQL-server-community-5.1.72-1.rhel5
        libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.4) is needed by MySQL-server-community-5.1.72-1.rhel5
        libpthread.so.0(GLIBC_2.3.4) is needed by MySQL-server-community-5.1.72-1.rhel5
        rtld(GNU_HASH) is needed by MySQL-server-community-5.1.72-1.rhel5
        libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.3.4) is needed by MySQL-client-community-5.1.72-1.rhel5
        libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.4) is needed by MySQL-client-community-5.1.72-1.rhel5
        rtld(GNU_HASH) is needed by MySQL-client-community-5.1.72-1.rhel5
```

Could anyone help me in installing?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Off-topic for SO; belongs on [sf]; also, what part of the error message do you not understand?

Comment: You have to check the dependencies for glibc before installing mysql-community-versions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It says you need `glibc` version 2.4 as a minimum, and 2.3.4 isn't there as well. Since [RHEL4 ends at 2.3.4](http://distrowatch.com/table.php?distribution=redhat) and you don't have it, your problem is either:

1. You're trying to install a RHEL5 RPM on a (pre-4.8) RHEL4 box.
2. You don't have the 32-bit versions of `glibc` installed on a RHEL5-64 box.

You said it's a 32-bit box, so it looks like the former. You might be able to rebuild the RPMs from the source one, but if your OS is that old, it's unlikely to work.